How To Copy Existing Service Fabric Image as a new image with a different version?
We currently deploy images to an on-prem service fabric cluster using powershell:
`
# Compress package to upload to the image store
Copy-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage `
    -ApplicationPackagePath "$path\pkg\Release" `
    -CompressPackage `
    -SkipCopy

# Copy package to the cluster image store 
Copy-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage `
    -ApplicationPackagePath "$path\pkg\Release" `
    -ApplicationPackagePathInImageStore $storePath `
    -TimeoutSec 1800

This happens for every service we have, which is around 30+ applications and around 60+ services (combination of stateless and actors).
In our build pipeline this takes a long time.  So we are looking into separating the process or only build projects that have changed.  So if one service changes, that only builds but our teams like to have the same package versions to support/restarts/etc.  So having a consistent version number is ideal (e.g. 2.5.0).
So if we only build a single NEW image, how can we take existing images that already exist in the image story and copy them as-is with a new version?  Is this even feasible?
The goal is also to speed up our pipeline.
Looking through: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/update-servicefabricapplicationupgrade?view=azureservicefabricps
I haven't found anything that looks viable to use.
I've tried researching other powershell modules to use but haven't found anything viable.
